# Grails spring security rest - overwrite token

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am having issues overwriting a token in the database for a user that already has a token.
Issue: POST request to api/v1/login generates new token in JSON-response, but the newly generated token that I receive is not stored in database if we already have a token for that user, the old token remains until the Quartz job remove it.

I expect the user to receive a new token(and also store it) if the user logs in again.

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to help you out on this: you plugin configuration, security filters, etc.

I suggest you save the token in *cache* instead of in the Database like the [documentation](http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/docs/guide/tokenStorage.html#grailsCache) specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Great suggestion, I will try it if the GORM implementation seem impossible.
Maybe it is just a config parameter? I searched the documentation but did not find anything.

Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/api/v1/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter',
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.useBearerToken = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.validation.headerName = 'X-Auth-Token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.endpointUrl = '/api/v1/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.useGorm = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenDomainClassName = 'backend.auth.AuthenticationToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.tokenValuePropertyName = 'token'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.token.storage.gorm.usernamePropertyName = 'username'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.passwordPropertyName = 'password'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useJsonCredentials = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rest.login.useRequestParamsCredentials = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a constraint on your AuthenticationToken that is preventing the new token from being saved in the database.

Doing another login will not replace the existing token, but will try and add a new entry to the AuthenticationToken table.

If you have a unique constraint on username, or some other non-null property added to your token class that isn't being populated, the call to save will fail with no warnings logged anywhere.

You can see this on GormTokenStorageService.groovy around line 65.

```
void storeToken(String tokenValue, UserDetails principal) {   
<snip>
    dc.withTransaction { status ->
            def newTokenObject = dc.newInstance((tokenValuePropertyName): tokenValue, (usernamePropertyName): principal.username)
            newTokenObject.save()
        }
```

There is no check to see if the token saved successfully.